# what is event here which is passed through the function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please tell what is **event** here which is passed through the function

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: We're not javascript interpreters. Why don't you `console.log` it?

Comment: Its a object of Event class! Consists info about the event as what, when, how, by who.

Comment: "The single argument passed to the specified event handler function is a MouseEvent object." [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your `onClick` handler, it will be called every time there is a "click" event triggered on the `window` object. The parameter that is passed to the `onClick` handler is the "click" event itself. This is a type of ["Event" object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

> The click event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a mouse's primary button) is pressed and released on a single element.

The object itself will contain some information about the event that was triggered, for example, in your code, you are inspecting `event.target` - this will contain the element that was the [target of the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (aka: where it came from).

Answer (score 0):

`event` is a parameter your `onclick` will pass to the `function` you defined as the `onclick` handler.

> All event objects in the DOM are based on the Event Object.
>
> Therefore, all other event objects (like MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent)
>   has access to the Event Object's properties and methods.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp).

You can check out its properties by temporarily modifying your function to

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
window.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

and then when you click on the tag having the `id` of `id01`, you will see the object in your Console in the Browser's Dev Tools.